# WHERE Clause only IF NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

I need help with my `SELECT`.

I got a field that can be `NULL` and in it there is stored a foreign-key.

```
SELECT * FROM beerImage WHERE beerBRewID = brewID AND beerBrandID = beerID <--- this can be NULL
```

So if it's `NULL` nothing happens.

How can I check if `beerID` is `NOT NULL` so I can use `"beerBrandID = beerID"`?

Comment: +1 because you have a table named beerImage

Comment: Could you clarify your problem a bit? The way I see it, in `beerImage` table there's a field `beerId` which is used as a foreign key, but is nullable, right? Do you need the collect the data from two tables at once?

Comment: Make it a +2 for the beerImage table name, you have my vote.

Comment: Please supply some example data and desired results. Not clear exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Table:Brew
ID=1
Name=Pils
Table:Brand
ID=1
Name=Becks
Table:Variation
ID=1
Name=NonAlkohol
Table:beer
ID=1
brewID=1
BrandID=1
variationID=NULL <-- cause it got alcohol.

I want to show the beer even if there is VARIATION or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include records where there's no match, you need an outer join

```
SELECT beer.id AS beerID,
 beer.barrelID AS barrelID,
 beer.imageID AS imageID,
 beer.title AS title,
 beer.map AS map,
 beer.longitude AS longitude, 
 beer.latitude AS latitude, 
 brand.name AS brandName, 
 brew.type AS brewType,
 image.name AS imageName, 
 variation.name AS variationName 
FROM brand, brew, image, beer
LEFT OUTER JOIN variation ON variation.ID = beer.VariationID
WHERE beer.id = %s 
AND md5(beer.memberID) = %s 
AND beer.review = 1 
AND brand.ID = beer.brandID 
AND brew.ID = beer.brewID 
AND image.ID = beer.imageID
```

Comment: this causes

Unknown column 'beer.VariationID' in 'on clause'

Comment: try moving beer to the end of the from

Answer (score 19):

You probably need something like this:

First example:

```
SELECT * FROM beerImage WHERE beerBRewID = brewID AND (beerID IS NULL OR beerBrandID = beerID)
```

Second Example:

```
SELECT * FROM beerImage WHERE beerBRewID = brewID AND beerID IS NOT NULL AND beerBrandID = beerID
```

The first example will allow you to show records which have beerID null along with the beers which beerBrandID is equal to beerID (both).

The second one will return exactly beers which correspond to beerBrandID (excluding NULL beerIDs).

Comment: If beerBrandId = beerId, beerId is definitely not null.

Comment: This is what I tried, but it sets the field to 1 and selects the wrong variation.

WHERE beer.id = %s AND md5(beer.memberID) = %s AND beer.review = 1 AND brand.ID = beer.brandID AND brew.ID = beer.brewID AND image.ID = beer.imageID AND (beer.variationID IS NULL OR variation.ID = beer.variationID)

Comment: This is the first example: `...IS NULL OR...` - which will return the null valued variationIDs, select the second one, above - `.. IS NOT NULL AND..`.

Comment: brand.ID = beer.brandID AND brew.ID = beer.brewID AND image.ID = beer.imageID AND beer.variationID IS NOT NULL AND variation.ID = beer.variationID

get no RESULT :-(

Answer (score 13):

How about using with `CASE` statement in where clause like

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN  beer.id IS NOT NULL 
    THEN beer.brand_id = 12345
    ELSE TRUE
END
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for null / not null, use IS NULL / IS NOT NULL

```
AND beerID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: WHERE beerBRewID = brewID AND beerBrandID = beerID AND beerID IS NOT NULL

like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "IS NULL" or "IS NOT NULL" MySQL comparison functions.

Read more about this here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null

Comment: THis ist my SELECT:

SELECT beer.id AS beerID, beer.barrelID AS barrelID, beer.imageID AS imageID, beer.title AS title, beer.`map` AS map, beer.longitude AS longitude, beer.latitude AS latitude, brand.name AS brandName, brew.type AS brewType, image.name AS imageName, variation.name AS variationName FROM beer, brand, brew, image, variation WHERE beer.id = %s AND md5(beer.memberID) = %s AND beer.review = 1 AND brand.ID = beer.brandID AND brew.ID = beer.brewID AND image.ID = beer.imageID AND variation.ID = beer.variationID

beer.variationID this can be NULL, if its NULL nothing will be selected